# Create new column by selecting dataframe subset based on current row value and sum another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, feature-engineering

Lets say we have a sample dataframe that looks like this

```
# Create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_posts': [4, 6, 3, 9, 1, 14, 2, 5, 7, 2,12],
                   'date' : ['2020-03-01', '2020-01-02', '2020-01-03', 
                            '2020-01-04', '2019-01-05', '2019-01-06', 
                            '2020-01-07', '2020-01-08', '2020-01-09', 
                            '2020-01-10','2020-01-11']})
cols=['num_posts']
```

Now i need to create features such as sum(num_posts) for last week of previous year, ratio of last week of prev year by last month of previous year etc.

What i am doing right now is

```
def create_calendar_columns(df,dt):
    df['day_number']= pd.to_datetime(df[dt]).dt.dayofyear
    df['week_number']= pd.to_datetime(df[dt]).dt.isocalendar().week
    df['year']= pd.to_datetime(df[dt]).dt.year
    return df
```

and then

```
def calculate_curr_year_sum(df,cols,dt):
    df=create_calendar_columns(df,dt)
    df[dt]=pd.to_datetime(df[dt])
    for col in cols:
         df['curr_year_sum_'+str(col)]= df.loc[df['year']==df[dt].dt.year,col].sum()  
          # sum of 'col' for all rows having same year as of current row value
```

But it **does not select the subset of dataframe having same year value**. Instead it take the sum of whole dataframe. It insert value=65 in all rows which is sum of "num_posts"

How can i select the subset of dataframe where rows with year equal to current row value for the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `df['year']==df[dt].dt.year` is `True` everywhere. You never iterate over the different years, so you won't see any different results for different years. What I think you want to do is a groupby transformation:

```
>>> df.groupby("year")["num_posts"].transform("sum")
0     50
1     50
2     50
3     50
4     15
5     15
6     50
7     50
8     50
9     50
10    50
```